# Array numbers sort without sort method and return new sorted array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to implement sort with aim of without copying old array and return new sorted array.
I have got some kind of success but having some bugs in my solution.

```js
function findMin(arr, from, minVal) {
  let minIdx = from || 0;
  for (let i = from || 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   
    if (arr[i] < arr[minIdx] && arr[i] > minVal) {
      minIdx = i;
    }
  }
  return arr[minIdx];
}

function sort(arr) {
  let sorted = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sorted.push(findMin(arr, 0, sorted[(sorted.length||1) - 1]||0 ));
  }
  return sorted;
}

//alert(sort([3, 1, 1]));
```

the above snippet working fine when there unique values.
I need help in fixing this. And how to make it more generic to do it in ascending and descending order.

I just want to reiterate that I don't want use native method and I don't want to copy or clone existing array. And the solution should return a new array.

Comment: Can I ask why you're doing this? I'd wager that `arr.slice().sort()` will outperform any implementation of a non-inplace sort you can write in JS. V8 uses quicksort and it's ultra-optimized and inplace, so the slight copy overhead from a `.slice()` call (also ultra-optimized) is a small penalty that shouldn't be a serious problem. If you don't care about performance, then basically look up timsort, mergesort, heapsort or quicksort and implement it and be prepared for it to be slower than V8.

Comment: I wanted to have my own implementation. I know that it may give bad performance.  Thanks for heads-up.